# return List values from Windows form class to another class

Tags: c#

### I'm sure this is super simple, but sadly, so am I.  Here is my class:

```
private List<string> colDescNode = new List<string>();

public List<string> ColDescNode
{
    get { return colDescNode; }
    set { colDescNode = value; } 
}

public TreeViewColorDescNodes()
{
    List<string> colDescNode = new List<string>();
    connect.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("RMM3DMTagColors", connect))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        using (SqlDataReader drReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (drReader.Read())
            {
                if (!drReader.IsDBNull(0))
                    colDescNode.Add(drReader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

And here is my form, so far. I have looked at other questions, but can't find an answer that I understand. Everything is too far beyond my skill level at this point.

```
public void fillTreeViewByList()
{
    connect.Open();

    TreeViewColorDescNodes firstNode = new TreeViewColorDescNodes();  // Everything from here down is probably wrong...

    tvDiscountMaintenance.Nodes.Add("Select All"); 
    foreach (var item in ColDescNode)
    {
        TreeNode colorDesc = new TreeNode(ColDescNode.ToString());
        tvDiscountMaintenance.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(item.ToString());  
    }
}
```

I'm trying to fill a Treeview, but that's a whole different set of problems. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please describe the desired results and where things go wrong.  Also, your class appears to be missing a `class` statement.

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `TreeViewColorDescNodes` but then never accessing it. Did you mean to use e.g.: `firstNode.ColDescNode` instead of just `ColDescNode`?

Comment: I can run the stored procedure in class TreeViewCodesDescNodes, but when I instantiate the class in my Form with: TreeViewColorDescNodes firstNode = new TreeViewColorDescNodes();  firstNode.ColDescNode is still empty. Count = 0.  I changed my Form code to match what Mukul Varshney suggested, and it seems to make good sense, but I still have the same problem. Please expound on "class appears to be missing a 'class' statement". Maybe that's where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try below. I used the notepad to edit the code so please excuse for any syntax mistakes

```
public void fillTreeViewByList()
{
    connect.Open();

    TreeViewColorDescNodes firstNode = new TreeViewColorDescNodes();  // Everything from here down is probably wrong...

    tvDiscountMaintenance.Nodes.Add("Select All"); 

    //firstNode has the instance of TreeViewColorDescNodes() which has list of items from DB
    //So you need to iterate the items from this instance
    foreach (string item in firstNode.ColDescNode)
    {
        //You need to create the tree node with text in item rather than List name
        TreeNode colorDesc = new TreeNode(item);

        //You need to add the tree node to the tree control rather than the string
        tvDiscountMaintenance.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(colorDesc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. If I move the List and the stored procedure into the Form method fillTreeViewByList then, with the code corrections you made, it works. But if I try to return the List from the class TreeViewColorDescNodes to the Form method fillTreeViewByList then firstNode is still empty. Count = 0.  I have almost given up. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: do you have any declaration of ColDescNode other than within TreeViewColorDescNodes class ? Also put a break point at tvDiscountMaintenance.Nodes.Add("Select All"); and see what's the count of firstNode.ColDescNode list ?